# Solution for this matrix equation?

Tags: linear-transformations, matrix-equations

How to find the 2-by-2 complex matrix $H$ (if there is one) for which
$$H\left[\begin{matrix} a & b \\ b^* & c\end{matrix}\right]H^\dagger=\left[\begin{matrix} a & be^{-i\lambda} \\ b^*e^{i\lambda} & c\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: What does $b^*$ mean? Conjugate of $b$? And $H^\dagger$? Tranpose, adjoint... of $H$?

Comment: @AugSB yes, $b^*$ is conjugate and $H^\dagger$ is conjugate transpose

Comment: Just multiplying and solving the resulting equation system may help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a & be^{-i\lambda} \\ b^*e^{i\lambda}&c\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}e^{-i\lambda} &\\ &1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\b^* &c\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\lambda} &\\ &1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: how did you come to know about this product?

Comment: @vidyarthi Just feeling that it should be something simple and I tried diagonal matrices.

Comment: @A.G. amazing, thank you!